# Oracle function cant pass in date - DAYS

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to pass date - DAYS to Oracle Function, but i kept getting error.

**This one working fine :**

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 730 DAYS
FROM
    dual;
```

**This one returns error:** ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
SELECT
    MYFUNCTION(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 730 DAYS)
FROM
    dual;
```

**When i change this to another SELECT, it works, but why is that so ??**
I really like the one above, since its easier + if I need to change it to MONTH or YEAR or whatever, its easy. But it doesn't work.

```
SELECT
    MYFUNCTION(
        (
        SELECT
            TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 730 DAYS
        FROM
            dual
        )
    )
FROM
    dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistakenly think you are dealing with an interval `730 DAYS`. But

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 730 DAYS FROM dual;
```

is

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 730 AS DAYS FROM dual;
```

So you calculate `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 730` where Oracle takes 730 to mean 730 days, as this is how adding or subtracting a number from a date is defined, and then you call this result column "DAYS".

This explains why

```
SELECT MYFUNCTION(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 730 DAYS) FROM dual;
```

results in a syntax error; you are using an alias name ("DAYS") where it doesn't belong.

Make this

```
SELECT MYFUNCTION(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 730) FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT MYFUNCTION(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '730' DAY(3)) FROM dual;
```

instead.